# Implement Minimax into my game

Tags: javascript, minimax

Would someone mind taking a look into my Tic-tac-toe javascript code and seeing why my compMove() function (which contains my minimax function) isn't firing? Here is a link to the full code with html & css: https://codepen.io/DRick504/pen/VWpEXv

```
function compMove() {

  function minimax(copyTwo, player) {

var newBoard = copyTwo.slice()

var score = 0

var availSpots = spotsLeft(newBoard) //returns array of available indexes

  if (checkWinner(newBoard,human)===true) {

      return score = 10

  } else if (checkWinner(newBoard,opp)===true) {

      return score = -10

  } else if (availSpots==='empty') {

      return score = 0
  }

var moves = []

  for (var i = 0; i < availSpots.length; i++){
//takes board and only goes through the available spots on the board. Then puts them in an object.
      var move = {};

      move.index = newBoard[availSpots[i]];

      newBoard[availSpots[i]] = player;

      if (player == opp){

        var result = minimax(newBoard, human);
        move.score = result.score;
      } else {
        var result = minimax(newBoard, opp);
        move.score = result.score;
      }

    newBoard[availSpots[i]] = move.index;

    moves.push(move);
  }

 var bestMove;

 if(player === opp){

var bestScore = -10000;
for(var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++){
  if(moves[i].score > bestScore){
    bestScore = moves[i].score;
    bestMove = i;
  }
}

} else{

var bestScore = 10000;
for(var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++){
  if(moves[i].score < bestScore){
    bestScore = moves[i].score;
    bestMove = i;
  }
}
}

return moves[bestMove];
}

var boardcopy = gameBoard.slice()

var makeMoves = minimax(boardcopy,opp)   

  $('.b'+makeMoves).removeClass('block')
  $('.b'+makeMoves).addClass(oppClass)
  $('.b'+makeMoves).text(opp)
  gameBoard[makeMoves]=opp



  turnsLeft++

 if (checkWinner(gameBoard,opp)===true) {

     alert ('You Lose! So Sorry! :\(')

 $('.Losses').text('Lost'+losses++)

     return reset()

   } else if (turnsLeft===9) {

      alert('It\'s a Draw!')

     return reset()

   }

 whosTurn=1

} //end of CompMove
```

Comment: Open your browser's Developer Console in your code pen. The errors are shown when you choose a block and are outside of your compMove function pasted here. They contain the exact line numbers and errors, so it should be a great starting point to tackle this on your own first.

Comment: `move.score = result.score;` - Cannot read property 'score' of undefined. Which means that `result` is undefined which further means that your `minimax()` function doesn't return a value.

Comment: @rgthree thanks a lot for your feedback!

Comment: @Botimoo thanks a lot for your feedback! I've made some changes based on it! Still troubleshooting though